# ElasticSearch NEST - Sorting by list of dates in a specific range

Tags: c#, sorting, elasticsearch, nest

I have some documents in elastic search with the following mapping (simplified)

```
{
    "primaryRecord": {
        "orderTrades": {
                "type" : "nested",
                "include_in_parent":true,
                "properties" : {
                    "materialDates": {"type" : "date", "index" : "not_analyzed", "include_in_all" : "false"},
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Now - I'm querying to get results based on a date range against the `materialDates` field (which is actually a List of dates on the index) - this is all fine. I'm having trouble sorting the results based on the matched result from the list dates, example:

Range Query: July 7, 2014 - July 14, 2014

Sample Docs

```
{
    orderTrades: [
        {
            materialDates: [3/13/2013, 7/10/2014, 8/10/2014]
        },
        {
            materialDates: [7/9/2014, 8/15/2014]
        }
    ]
}
```

Both documents match the range filter, but when sorting ascending, the second object should come first, but the `3/13/2013` value is considered in the sort and thus comes first. Is there a way to only sort on the matched array value? Current NEST that I'm using:

```
query.Sort(
    x => x.OnField(j => j.OrderTrades.Select(z => z.MaterialDates))
        .NestedPath(h => h.OrderTrades)
        .NestedFilter(q => q.Range(
           v => v.OnField("orderTrades.materialDates").From(fromRange).To(toRange)
        ))
        .ToggleSort(true)
);
```

Also restricted to elastic 0.9. Thanks for any ideas - let me know if more info is needed

Comment: Your source code is missing the query declaration so I am unable to replicate.  What is query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tricky requirement because the behaviour that you ask for is ambiguous because you're trying to sort on an array value.  I think that what you want to happen is for it to sort on the smallest value in the array that is in the range of the query.  However that's assuming an ascending sort; would you want a descending sort to go on the largest value?

All things considered, that's a specific enough requirement that I don't think there's an easy way, but you could possibly achieve this with a [script-based sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting).  The script would have to replicate the query range and replace any values outside of the range with something really low or really high depending on the sort order.
Scripts are pretty powerful, as you can use Groovy, and the [elasticsearch docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) are pretty good.

Having said that, the note in the script sorting docs is an interesting one:

> Note, it is recommended, for single custom based script based sorting, to use function_score query instead as sorting based on score is faster.

You don't say whether you're using scoring in your query, but if not you could use [function_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_using_function_score) to implement your sorting requirement with a similar piece of script.

Comment: Yeah - I ended up using a child document with more specific data - attempted a few script sorts but didn't make it far. Appreciate the input (and sorry for the lack of feedback, got busy)

Answer (score 0):

In your sample you have a single orderTrades document with 2 of your nested materialDates.  ES will not sort materialDates **within** a single orderTrades document.  When you sort results in ES it sorts the order in which the entire orderTrades documents are returned.

I think that if you were using ES 1.x you could use perhaps use nested queries to do what you want, but that isn't supported in 0.9